# MATLAB: How to solve linear system modulo m

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

Does anyone know what functions are available for solving linear systems when the equations are actually congruences mod `m`? The desire is to solve a linear system (A*x = b) for values x in which "A*x is congruent to b"

A discussion of how to perform gaussian elimination in this situation [can be found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211955/how-can-i-use-gauss-elimination-to-solve-equations-with-modular-arithmetics), but I was hoping to use MATLAB rather than attempting to do it by hand.

Comment: do you mean you want to solve a linear system for values in which it becomes congruent? (two values are congruent right, not equations?)

Comment: @FredrikRedin, I mean a linear system like "`A*x` is (elementwise) congruent to `b`". Just like the normal "`A*x = b`" linear system, but with congruence instead of equality.

Comment: Yes, we are saying the same things with different words. =). Interesting problem btw.

Comment: Ah, ok, wasn't sure exactly what you meant. Yeah, it's pretty cool!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the lincon() method found here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32856-system-of-linear-congruences/content/lincon.m

Comment: Sorry, it seems I spoke to soon; that's a useful method, but it doesn't appear to support solving solving for multiple variables.