# Solving a set of linear equations over binary field

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I need to solve a set of linear equations over the binary field, namely, I have a matrix M and I need to find a vector v such that M.v=0 (mod 2), where the entries of matrix M and vector v are all 0 or 1 and on the right hand side is a vector whose all components are even numbers. Is there any good way to program it in Mathematica or Matlab?

Comment: This was asked [before][1] on stackoverflow, search for linear congruences:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339989/matlab-how-to-solve-linear-system-modulo-m

Comment: What size is `v`? Is a brute-force approach feasible?

Comment: @Bram, thank you, but that algorithm does not apply to multi-variable case

Comment: In Mathematica, `NullSpace[m, Modulus->2]` will do this.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns of `M` is not too large, a brute-force approach can be used:

```
M = [0 1 0 1; 1 0 0 1; 1 1 1 0]; %// example matrix M
V = (dec2bin(0:2^size(M,2)-1)-'0').'; %// all possible vectors v, as columns of V
ind = all(mod(M*V, 2)==0); %// index of solution vectors
solutions = V(:,ind); %// each column is a solution vector
```

In this example,

```
solutions =
     0     1
     0     1
     0     0
     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but M and v typically have several hundred entries...

Comment: The "mod" operation on RHS may make brute force neccessary.